# I have a multiple level <IFRAMES> script; how do I access a particular text box inside a IFRAME that is within another IFRAME

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to use Selenium to access a text box that is inside a nested IFRAME structure.
Below is the structure.

```
<frameset border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" rows="120,*"> 
<frame name="start_main" scrolling="no" noresize target="contents" src="start_main"> 
<frameset cols="139,*"> 
<frame name="start_sub" scrolling="no" target="main" src="start_sub"> 
<frame name="start_body" src="start_body"> 
</frameset> 
<noframes> 
<body> 
<p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p> 
</body> 
</noframes> 
</frameset>
```

The text box I need to access is in "start_body"

```
<input type="integer" name="part_num" size="14" style="font-size: 8pt" value="">
```

I have used Selenium to log in and to enter text in non IFRAME pages but this has me stumped.

This is what I have tried so far.

This is the code I have tried so far.

```
    driver.switch_to.frame('start_body')
    sleeptime = random.uniform(time_min, time_max)
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
    #
    # enter the part number
    #
    part_num = "394914008"
    # switch to the frame containing the input fields
    #
    driver.switch_to.frame('start_body')
    ascen_field =     driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/center/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/font/small/input")      
    ascen_field.send_keys(inst_value);`
```

Comment: those are oldschool frames... you may need to get into frameset, then frame, then frameset, and finally into the frame inside of that... (so that's 4 driver.switchtos...)  First switch to XPATH of //frameset[contains(@rows, '120')]  (use webdriverwait with exepected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement) )  Then to //frame[@name='start_main'] , then to //framset[contains(@cols, '139')], then to //frame[@name='start_body'].